# How to deploy all services for a preview environment without rebuilding them all when one changes

Tags: kubernetes, continuous-integration, deployment, microservices

I am trying to create a preview environment for each pull request. We are using a monorepo with about 2 dozen microservice. To have a fully functional preview environment we need all the services to be launched.

The challenge I am facing is how to deploy all of the different microservices when our current pipeline only builds and deploys the microservice(s) that changed. My thought was to create a helm chart that contains sub charts. Each sub chart would be a microservice so I should be able to just run a `helm install` and all of them will deploy to the specific namespace.
I wonder how I would determine what tag to use for launching the microservices that were not changed? In theory the preview environment is just QA so my thought was when a commit/merge is made to the develop branch (QA) it would tag that microservice with `latest-qa` and the `sha1` of the commit. The default value for the image tag in the helm chart would be `latest-qa` and then I would manually override the tag for the microservice(s) that changed.

I know I am not the only person to do such a thing so I am wondering if I can get feedback on my approach from someone that has done this before or a recommendation of tools to make this easier.